# D3.js map not appearing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been getting started on D3.js, and JSON, and I've followed instructions that I've read, but when I run the code below, the D3.js code for the map does not appear. us-10m.v1.json is the file of the GeoJSON. Any hint is appreciated. Thank you!

```
<html>
<body>
    <style>

    .states :hover {
      fill: red;
    }

    .state-borders {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 0.5px;
      stroke-linejoin: round;
      stroke-linecap: round;
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    </style>
    <svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>


    var svg = d3.select("svg");

    var path = d3.geoPath();

    d3.json("us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
      if (error) throw error;

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "states")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
        .enter().append("path")
          .attr("d", path);

      svg.append("path")
          .attr("class", "state-borders")
          .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })));
    });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My first thought would be you aren't importing the topojson library, only D3. `topojson` should be undefined in your code - which should cause an error. Some additional details may help narrow down the issue if this isn't it: Are there paths in the DOM (not visible doesn't mean not appended), are there any errors in the console, where did you get your json file (and is it actually topojson and not geojson)?

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you! What is really weird, is that when I put in a link to the file, it worked, but once I downloaded it, it stopped working.